# Excel MSsql different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel-formula

I have create a table named:

```
sub
```

,with field:

```
addn numeric (24,6) NULL
```

I have used the values in this txt file to insert. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2ixHDOvHiM5bqDSI3fCbkuXa0Syfjrn/view

Question:
Why is it the if I query this:

```
select SUM(addn) from sub
```

Result:

```
131546008007.610000
```

and if I paste the result of this in Excel:

```
 select * from sub
```

the sum is:

```
131546008007.57
```

Note:
there are 4 (-0.01) in the query. I don't know if this is trigger and how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is topic about Precision, Scale and Length. Numeric datatype is stored/managed in different way than float datatype, for instance.

Try this query, and you will have the same result than in Excel:

```
select sum(cast(addn as float)) from sub
```

`131546008007.57`

Here you have some links where they are explaining that the float datatype is an approximate number, and the decimal is more accurate than the float datatype. So you can see with this than Excel is using approximate numbers.

[Precision, Scale, and Length](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx) they are explaining than in financial applications you should NOT use floating-point datatypes, so it is good you're using `numeric` in your DB, and therefore you can rely on your SQL DB in this example.

And [here](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) they state that:

> Excel was designed in accordance to the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754). The standard defines how floating-point numbers are stored and calculated. The IEEE 754 standard is widely used because it allows-floating point numbers to be stored in a reasonable amount of space and calculations can occur relatively quickly.

.

> **Excel store 15 significant digits of precision.**

Comment: Thanks mate. by any chance can you is there a way to convert excel data type from float to numeric? thanks again

Comment: You're welcome @AnthonyLopez, I guess you can't use Excel in this way. Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel) which has more explanation. Or even check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) if you want to know more _scientific_ stuff regarding this.
I guess you should rather stay with DB's in this case, and remember: the biggest precision, the slowest response in mathematical operations. Good luck!